Venting bathroom without access to main vent stack
I live in Newfoundland, Canada and I am adding a bathroom on the main level. There is an existing addition that currently has the main bathroom but it needs to be removed so I am converting one room into a bathroom / laundry room with a tub/shower combo, double sink, toilet, and washer.
The house has a bathroom in the garage and one in the master bedroom, both in a later addition to the house separate from where the new bathroom is going. There is currently no vent stack going through the attic in this part of the house. I would be running a branch off the main line, which is directly below the bathroom.
What options do I have for properly venting this bathroom? I would rather not have to cut a hole in the roof for a new vent stack. Can I use AAV to vent the bathroom? Are there any pros vs. cons for this or is my only option to suck it up and cut a hole?

As I understand it a toilet requires an external vent, that is air admittance valves are not allowed on toilets. So you need to pipe into the attic and branch back into the existing vent stack or make a new hole in the roof for for a new vent, or pipe through the wall and make or connect to an exterior vent stack.

Air admittance valves may be allowable by your local code; you'll have to confirm that. However, you ask for options to properly vent this bathroom, and that would be to add a proper vent to either an existing vent or a new one through the roof.
How to do this will depend on the configuration of the fixtures being added and the structural layout of your house. You likely will require more than one vent.
The new vents can be connected together in the ceiling space of the floor they are on and then a single vent runs up into the attic, or if the attic is directly above, pipe them separately and connect them together in the attic. Once in the attic, you can either continue to run the vent over to an existing vent or make a new penetration through the roof.
If you decide to go with AAV(s) I would recommend that you still pipe the vent(s) into the attic space and install the AAV(s) there where they will remain accessible, and you can always pipe them through the roof at a later time if you have issues with them.
